# Solidworks API ExportToDWG2

Tags: python, vba, api, com, solidworks

I am attempting to convert a script from VBA to Python that one of our engineers has written.  It changes some values in a Solidworks drawing and then exports some dwg files.  This is part of a larger project where we will generate many files.  Everything is working except being able to export to DWG files.

When the ExportToDWG2 function runs in VBA it generates the files fine.

```
Dim varAlignment As Variant
Dim dataAlignment(11) As Double
Dim varViews As Variant
Dim dataViews(0) As String

dataAlignment(0) = 0#
dataAlignment(1) = 0#
dataAlignment(2) = 0#
dataAlignment(3) = 1#
dataAlignment(4) = 0#
dataAlignment(5) = 0#
dataAlignment(6) = 0#
dataAlignment(7) = 0#
dataAlignment(8) = 0#
dataAlignment(9) = 0#
dataAlignment(10) = 0#
dataAlignment(11) = 1#
varAlignment = dataAlignment
dataViews(0) = "*Top"
varViews = dataViews
sModelName = swModel.GetPathName
sPathName = "c:\projects\1234.dxf"
swModel.ExportToDWG2 sPathName, sModelName, swExportToDWG_ExportAnnotationViews, True, varAlignment, False, False, 0, varViews
```

When the ExportToDWG2 function runs in Python it returns False but does not cause an error with parameter types.

```
# Save the DFX
da = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
data_align = win32.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_VARIANT, da)
varViews = win32.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_VARIANT, ["*Top"])
sPathName = "c:\projects\1234.dxf"
swExportToDWG_ExportAnnotationViews = 3
stat = swModel.ExportToDWG2(
    sPathName, swModel.GetPathName,
    swExportToDWG_ExportAnnotationViews, True,
    data_align, False, False, 0, varViews
)

print(sPathName, stat)
```

Any ideas how to get ExportToDWG2 to work in Python as it does in VBA or any ideas to debug what may be happening?

Comment: The name `GetPathName` indicates that it might be a method (callable) instead of a plain attribute. It seems that in VBA a method that takes no parameters doesn't need to be followed by parentheses when called, so the VBA code is ambiguous in that regard. However, it sounds very much like a method name, so I would try to call it using `swModel.GetPathName()` in the Python code.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this might be too late to answer this but the answer is using ExportToDWG instead of ExportToDWG2 at least this worked in VB .net.